# Tracking history in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, version-control

there is any possibility to track changes in Excel XP? With time, content and name of editor? Excel is running under just one windows account so system of revisions cant handle name of editors.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [share the workbook](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel/HP052025951033.aspx) and Excel will then track changes in it, but this is linked to the `Application.Username` property and, from the sounds of it, in your situation this will always be the same user as it is linked to the application install and therefore the Windows account.

The only way I could think of getting round this is forcing users to 'login' when the workbook is opened using a little bit of VBA.

Comment: So just compromise, tracking changes without tracking editors name... XP and 2007 seems same in this.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use something like [subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/) (or Sharepoint) that handles versioning, and have users check-out the file and check it back in.